# Lanzo un executor pero solo se ejecuta un hilo

Tags: java, hilos, executorservice

Mi cuestión era que al intentar hacer una función con un ejecutor( en este caso una multiplicacion de matrices)  y al comprobar el hilo que se encontraba en el run siempre me salía el mismo, 12.

```
/*
Atributos de la clase
*/
    public int x,y;
    public  int matriz2[][];
    public  int matres[][];
    public int mattriz1[][];

    /*Constructor de la clase*/
    public prodMatConcurrente(int [][] mat1,int [][] mat2,int[][] matres,int x){
        this.x=x;
        this.mattriz1 = mat1;
        this.matriz2 = mat2;
        this.matres = matres;
    }



    public void run(){
       for(int i = 0;i<matriz2.length;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<matriz2.length;j++){
                matres[x][i]=matres[x][i] + mattriz1[x][j] * matriz2[j][i];
            }
        }
        long threadId = prodMatConcurrente.currentThread().getId();
          System.out.println("I am thread " + threadId);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        double tiempo_inicial = 0;
        int nNuc = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        float Cb = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);
        int tamPool = (int)(nNuc/(1-Cb));
        System.out.println("El numero de hilos es:" +tamPool);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println("Introduzca la primera dimension de la matriz");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduzca la segunda dimension de la matriz");
        int y = sc.nextInt();
        int mat[][] = new int[x][y];
        int mat2[][] = new int[x] [y];
        int matres[][] = new int [x][y];
        //Inicializamos la matriz resultado
        for(int i = 0; i<x;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<y;j++){
                matres[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        //Rellenamos la matriz con random
      for(int i = 0; i<x;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<y;j++){
                mat[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
                }
            }
       //imprime la primera matriz
        /*for(int i = 0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<y;j++){
                System.out.print(" "+mat[i][j]+" ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }*/
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        //Rellenamos la segunda matriz
         for(int i = 0; i<x;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<y;j++){
                mat2[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
            }
        }
        /*for(int i = 0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<y;j++){
                System.out.print(" "+mat2[i][j]+" ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }*/
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        prodMatConcurrente [][] h = new prodMatConcurrente[x][y];

        int tamPool2=Math.round(x/tamPool);
        tiempo_inicial = System.nanoTime();
        //Ejecutor que tiene de tamaño la dimensión de la fila de la matriz  
        //entre el resultado de la ecuación de Subramanian
        ExecutorService exe= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(tamPool2);
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
            exe.execute(new prodMatConcurrente(mat,mat2,matres,i));
        }


        exe.shutdown();
        while(!exe.isTerminated()){}
        //exe.awaitTermination(100,TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        long finTiempo = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("El tiempo que ha tardado en ejecutrase es  "+(finTiempo-tiempo_inicial)/1.0e9);
        /*for(int i = 0;i<x;i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<y;j++){
                System.out.print(" "+matres[i][j]+" ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }*/
    }   
}
```

El mínimo de hilos que crea al hacer la ecuación de Subramian con `arg[0]=0` es 8 por lo que para una matriz de 8x8 tendría que ser 1 hilo por fila o así debería ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la lógica que tienes ahora, si `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` te devuelve 5 procesadores o más (muy probable), esto resultará en que vas a crear un thread pool con un solo thread:

```
ExecutorService exe= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(tamPool2); // tamPool2 == 1?
```

Ironicamente, si tienes 4 procesadores o menos, entonces tu thread pool creará mas de un thread, y el trabajo se efectuará de forma paralela, pero esto no parece ser tu caso.

---

Si seguimos tu lógica por etapas asumiendo 8 procesadores en tu máquina por tomar un ejemplo:

1. Según lo que mencionas, establezcamos que que `args[0] == "0"` y `x == 8` (la dimensión de la matriz.
2. `Cb = 0` (`float Cb = Float.parseFloat(args[0]);`).
3. `nNuc = 8` (`int nNuc = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();`)
4. `tamPool = 8` (`int tamPool = (int)(nNuc/(1-Cb)); //   8/(1-0)`)
5. `tamPool2 = 1`!!! = `int tamPool2=Math.round(x/tamPool); //   8/8`

Y siendo que `tamPool2` es la variable que usas para establecer el tamaño del thread pool, acabas con un solo thread.

La verdad es que no entiendo tu lógica. Pero si tu intención es que quieres que cada fila de la matriz pueda procesarse de forma paralela, entonces necesitas que el thread pool tenga por lo menos `x` hilos (`x` siendo la cantidad de filas en tu matriz).

De modo que en vez de usar `tamPool2` para crear el thread pool, que parece ser erróneo, simplemente usa `x`:

```
ExecutorService exe= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(x); // x == 8
```

Comment: tienes razon, lo que pasa es que no había caido en eso porque ponía hilo 12 y pensaba que se habían creado más de 12 hilos